# uso de ajax para invocar un script

Tags: php, html

Espero puedan apoyarme, tengo un código donde quiero mandar llamar un script de PHP mediante un botón, pero cuando hago clic en el botón si entra a la función, pero no ejecuta el script.

```
$nameIndice='envia'.$indice;
            //$check= "<a href='RetornoAccesorio.php?id=".$fila['num_ID']." '
              //      <span ><i class='fa-solid fa-person-walking-arrow-loop-left'></i></span></a>";
            //echo "<form action='insertar_equipoAlmcenDB.php' method='GET' id='formAlmacen'>";
                    $check= "<input class='form-control input-lg mt-2' type='number' id=".$fila['num_ID']." '
                    >";
                    $check2= "<input type='button' href='javascript:;' value='mod' id=".$fila['num_ID']." class='btn btn-info mt-2' onclick = 'accion(2);'>
                    ";
                    $check3= "<a href='#' onclick = 'accion();' id=".$fila['num_ID']." '
                    <span ><i class='fa-solid fa-person-walking-arrow-loop-left'></i></span></a>";
            
            $indice=$indice+1;       
            $salida.= "<tr>
                            <td><a href='muestraInfoAccesorios.php?id=".$fila['num_ID']."'>".$fila['num_ID']."</a></td>
                            <td>".$res."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['empresa']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['item']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['descripcion']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['costo_venta_unitario']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['qty']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['serie']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['proyecto']."</td>
                            <td>".$check."</td>
                            <td>".$check2."</td>
                            <td>"."<a href='eliminarEquipoANI.php?id=".$fila['num_ID']."   
                                    '<span ><i class='fa-solid fa-trash-can text-danger'></i></span></a>"."</td>
                            
                        </tr>";
            
             //"</form>";          
        } 
        
        $salida.="</tbody></table>";                
    } else{
        $salida.= "No hay datos :(";
    }
    echo $salida;
    $mysqli->close();
?>

 
<script>
    function accion()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST', //aqui puede ser igual get
            url: './mifuncion.php',//aqui va tu direccion donde esta tu funcion php
            data: {id:4},//aqui tus datos
            success:function(data){
                //lo que devuelve tu archivo mifuncion.php
           },
           error:function(data){
            //lo que devuelve si falla tu archivo 
           }
         });
    }
</script>
```

y el script que tengo por fuera es:

```
<?php
//mi accion
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo "accion";
print_r($id);
?>.
```

Pero no pasa nada al apretar el botón.

Comment: Saludos. En la primer parte del código; parece tienes espacio entre el `onclick`, `=` y `'accion();`'; quita esos espacios. En la última parte del código; donde hay solo código PHP ese `echo "accion";` es una salida de texto o debiera ser la invocación de la función; si debe ser invocar la función le falta; debe ser `echo "accion();";`.

Comment: puse solo una salida de texto para ver que si ejecute el script, pero no aparece nada